# How to fix Bad request response from IIS express 7 for one request from internet

Tags: iis, asp.net, iis-express

I'm trying  IISExpress 7 in Windows XP to servr requests from internet for ASP .NET MVC2 applicaton

I changed line in iisexpress 7 applicationhost.config from

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
```

to

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":80:" />
```

Request

```
GET http://1.2.3.4/Grid/Validate?_column=Toode&_entity=RidO&Toode=ooooo HTTP/1.1
Cookie: active=1; .EevaAuth=CF57FC098F341A1230626D5E339C9E94FE2D77157AAE54402DC2AB5F1AE1E079A9CB93B88B5479B4E926D3C6CDFF7D994E8FA1381CA32D20245A2A9C493B992F2E8863EA6C8E080886EDA103926096CB83B033490552F3CB9BFF62ABD5CFBA5181F378888BFF96D51400319AF8955B556D50A866
Host: 1.2.3.4
```

from internet causes Bad Request error:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 2.0
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: Eeva ERP
Date: Thu, 24 Nov 2011 11:52:30 GMT
Content-Length: 11

Bad Request
```

If request is issed form localhost, this exception does not occur.
All solutions which I have found describe that this is caused by ad characters in url. 
URL if this request `http://1.2.3.4/Grid/Validate` (ip addres changed) does not contain invalid characters.

How to allow this request form internet to be processed?

Comment: For those having this problem; check this: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/using-iis-express/handling-url-binding-failures-in-iis-express

Comment: Also our free VS extension 'Conveyor' allows IIS Express to be accessed externally https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the IIS logs at C:\inetpub\logs\wmsvc#. Your request might be coming in with HTML encoded characters instead of URL encoded like this:

```
http://1.2.3.4/Grid/Validate?_column=Toode&amp;_entity=RidO&amp;Toode=ooooo
```

If that's not the case, this [Microsoft KnowledgeBase](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820129) article might help you (it states windows server 2003 but if I remember correctly it could also apply to XP).